# Como configurar o LUA_PATH?

Tags: lua

Eu instalei o IUP (*toolkit gráfico*) em uma determinada pasta. Quando executo o seguinte script de dentro dessa pasta, o mesmo funciona perfeitamente..

```
require("iuplua")
iup.Message('Minha Aplicação','Finalizada com sucesso!')
```

O arquivo iuplua.so é um atalho que aponta para */usr/lib/libiuplua52.so*. Esse arquivo existe no diretório de instalação e há uma cópia em */usr/lib/lua/5.2/iuplua.so*

O problema acontece quando saio desse diretório e tento executar a mesma aplicação, obtenho essa mensagem de erro:

```
    lua: error loading module 'iuplua' from file './iuplua.lua':
    ./iuplua.lua:142: too many C levels (limit is 200) in main function near '"Toggle Text"'
stack traceback:
[C]: in ?
[C]: in function 'require'
./iuplua.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
./iuplua.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
./iuplua.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
./iuplua.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
...
```

Se verifico o caminho de pesquisa dentro do interpretador Lua:

```
> print (package.cpath)
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so;./?.so
```

Não sou muito experiente no GNU-Linux, mas me parece um problema no caminho de pesquisa... o chamado LUA_PATH... é isso mesmo? Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o problema era ridiculamente simples....

Na verdade criei um script de testes chamado *iuplua.lua*. Essa escolha do nome foi infeliz, pois o *require* exigia um arquivo *iuplua.so*. No entanto o mecanismo de pesquisa do lua (*lua_path*) encontrava primeiro o arquivo (de mesmo nome) com extensão ***lua***:

```
/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua
```

(notem a última opção: "**./?.lua**"!)

Com isso o meu programa de testes foi confundido com a biblioteca **.so** e o programa mencionado na pergunta não foi executado.

Comment: Se não me engano, agora que já se passaram alguns dias vc pode marcar a sua própria resposta como aceita.